# WARNING in Glassfish about JMS

Tags: glassfish, jms

I have recently installed the latest Glassfish open source version and configure it but I have problem with JMS and now my 2 Glassfish servers have problem (whereas before installing new GF server, it was working on the previous GF server). So I think there is probably conflict between these 2 servers.

When I try to use JMS, I receive these logs :

```
[#|2013-03-20T14:10:00.015+0100|FINE|glassfish3.1.2|javax.jms.ConnectionFactory.mqjmsra|_ThreadID=152;_ThreadName=Thread-2;ClassName=com.sun.messaging.jms.ra.DirectConnectionFactory;MethodName=createConnection;|MQJMSRA_DCF1101: createConnection():|#]

[#|2013-03-20T14:10:00.015+0100|FINE|glassfish3.1.2|javax.jms.ConnectionFactory.mqjmsra|_ThreadID=152;_ThreadName=Thread-2;ClassName=com.sun.messaging.jms.ra.DirectConnectionFactory;MethodName=createConnection;|MQJMSRA_DCF1101: createConnection(u,p):username=guest|#]

[#|2013-03-20T14:10:00.015+0100|FINE|glassfish3.1.2|javax.jms.Connection.mqjmsra|_ThreadID=152;_ThreadName=Thread-2;ClassName=com.sun.messaging.jms.ra.DirectConnection;MethodName=createSession;|MQJMSRA_DC1101: connectionId=7032438472106962688:createSession():isTransacted=false:acknowledgeMode=1|#]

[#|2013-03-20T14:10:00.015+0100|FINE|glassfish3.1.2|javax.jms.Session.mqjmsra|_ThreadID=152;_ThreadName=Thread-2;ClassName=com.sun.messaging.jms.ra.DirectSession;MethodName=close;|MQJMSRA_DS1101: sessionId=7032438472122322689:close()|#]

[#|2013-03-20T14:10:00.015+0100|FINE|glassfish3.1.2|javax.jms.Connection.mqjmsra|_ThreadID=152;_ThreadName=Thread-2;ClassName=com.sun.messaging.jms.ra.DirectConnection;MethodName=close;|MQJMSRA_DC1101: connectionId=7032438472106962688:close():|#]

[#|2013-03-20T14:10:00.046+0100|FINE|glassfish3.1.2|javax.jms.Connection.mqjmsra|_ThreadID=152;_ThreadName=Thread-2;ClassName=com.sun.messaging.jms.ra.DirectConnection;MethodName=_unsetClientID;|MQJMSRA_DC1101: connectionId=7032438472106962688:_unsetClientID():|#]

[#|2013-03-20T14:10:06.796+0100|FINE|glassfish3.1.2|javax.jms.ConnectionFactory.mqjmsra|_ThreadID=42;_ThreadName=Thread-2;ClassName=com.sun.messaging.jms.ra.DirectConnectionFactory;MethodName=createConnection;|MQJMSRA_DCF1101: createConnection():|#]

[#|2013-03-20T14:10:06.796+0100|FINE|glassfish3.1.2|javax.jms.ConnectionFactory.mqjmsra|_ThreadID=42;_ThreadName=Thread-2;ClassName=com.sun.messaging.jms.ra.DirectConnectionFactory;MethodName=createConnection;|MQJMSRA_DCF1101: createConnection(u,p):username=guest|#]

[#|2013-03-20T14:10:06.796+0100|FINE|glassfish3.1.2|javax.jms.Connection.mqjmsra|_ThreadID=42;_ThreadName=Thread-2;ClassName=com.sun.messaging.jms.ra.DirectConnection;MethodName=setExceptionListener;|MQJMSRA_DC1101: connectionId=7032438472106962688:setExceptionListener()|#]

[#|2013-03-20T14:10:06.796+0100|WARNING|glassfish3.1.2|javax.jms.Connection.mqjmsra|_ThreadID=42;_ThreadName=Thread-2;|MQJMSRA_DC2001: Unsupported:setExceptionListener():inACC=false:connectionId=7032438472106962688|#]

[#|2013-03-20T14:10:06.796+0100|FINE|glassfish3.1.2|javax.jms.Connection.mqjmsra|_ThreadID=42;_ThreadName=Thread-2;ClassName=com.sun.messaging.jms.ra.DirectConnection;MethodName=_unsetClientID;|MQJMSRA_DC1101: connectionId=7032438472106962688:_unsetClientID():|#]
```

I didn't find anything on Google...anybody to help me ?

Answer (score 0):

The cause was a Java library deployed in `${GLASSFISH_HOME}/glassfish/domains/domain1/lib` in `Milestone` state. Gone back to the latest release solved the problem.